# SSRS report, is there a way to switch templates based on configuration?

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I have been googling for a good description of this but am not having much luck. I am pretty new to SSRS reports and I am probably not using the correct terminology here. If someone could point me towards an article that describes this that would suffice.

Basically I want to pull a bit into my report, and based on the value of that bit (or maybe a varchar) I want to render an address in different formats, or add/remove some sections completely form the report. I suspect this is basic functionality but am having trouble finding an example. Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a table/matrix the best place to put stuff like this is in columns that are outside of the detail or any groups at the top of the table. You can merge all the cells and add rectangles to add specific formatting. The neat part about using header columns is they can be hidden and the space used will not be rendered.

Say you have a table and Row1 and Row2 contain different formatting of the same data. If you have a report parameter named ShowFormat1 then you can optionally hide/show the correct row with formatting.

```
Click Row one and Set its Hidden property to =!Parameters!ShowFormat1.Value
Click Row two and Set its Hidden property to =Parameters!ShowFormat1.Value
```

The same concept can be applied to all elements if you are not using a table or matrix. Non-repeating controls, Rectangle or Image for example, can be hidden but the space used will still be rendered.